# How to refer to an event inside a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to refer to the event type here, I can refer to the element however.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zuNhX/)

```
var app = {

    open : function(el) {

                //Want to run this.. dont know how to refer to event properly
                if(jQuery(e.target).is('.cantOpen')){
                     e.preventDefault();
                     return;
                 }

                 jQuery(el).toggleClass('opened') 

         },
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //Prefer this
    jQuery('.main').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            app.open(this)
    });

    //Ideally I dont want to add the code inside here but this does work
    jQuery('.main').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(jQuery(e.target).is('.cantOpen')){
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            app.open(this)
    });


});
```

Hopefully you see my angle here... I would like to learn how to refer to the event type inside my `open` function? Is it possible? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zuNhX/)

Comment: Just pass it as argument? `app.open(this, e)` and define `.open` to accept a second argument.

Comment: el refers to the element `.main`

Comment: @FelixKling didnt even know I could.. let me try

Comment: This code is confusing. In one place you are using `e.target` and in another `el` for the same thing. Be consistent, the references to `el` can be removed entirely and then you would call the function as `app.open(e)`.

Comment: @Jon He uses el - `jQuery(el).toggleClass('opened')`

Comment: @Archer: `jQuery(e.target).toggleClass('opened')`.

Comment: Yeah I refer to the element, I want to also refer to the event.. both.. @Jon OO good idea I didnt know you could do that :) That means event target right?

Comment: @FelixKling you understood me.. that worked well :) I definitely learned something here... Jon going to try yours.. both seem would work well..

Answer (score 1):

You can pass both the event and the element to the called function.

```
var app = {
    open : function(el,ev) {
```

and call it

```
$('.main').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        app.open(this,e)
```

Comment: Yeah I didnt realize that el is an argument that passes.. well lets just say I learned and this is VERY useful information :)